# Scatter plotting geographical coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column Loc in my dataframe that contains coordinates I want to plot
I transform it into an array with

```
z =pd.DataFrame(df.Loc)
z.to_numpy()
```

Which gives the following output:

```
array([['45.34301499763467, -73.80926407774574'],
       ['45.8563638, -73.9631463'],
                ...
      ['45.43701969433377, -73.24177014564303']], dtype=object)
```

I've attempted to use

```
x,y = z.T
```

But run into a "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)", I believe that is due to the '' inside the brackets. How do I transform this array to be able to plot it?

Comment: there's a few troubles - the first is that the coordinates are _strings_, not _floating point values_ as you may expect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataFrames can generally not contain more complex types, such as lists or tuples. Hence your cordinates are strings.
You can use `ast.literal.eval` to evaluate your strings directly from dataframe for instance with list comprehension:

```
import ast
z = np.array([ast.literal_eval(row) for row in df['Loc']])
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!